# Silent login to azure active directory in ASP.NET MVC Core 2 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

Let's say I have login form on a page. I type my username and password and
I want to log in to azure active directory in ASP.NET MVC Core 2 application without redirecting to *login.microsoft.com.*

Is it possible to do?

Comment: Yes it is, but could you explain why you want to do that? The one possible way exists in the standard as a legacy upgrade path, and unless you are upgrading a legacy app, it is not recommended for use.

Comment: @juunas For ex, I don't want to show that the app works on Azure, don't want to confuse a user